# Android PWA home screen shortcut

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I've set a website up as a PWA. When browsing with Android Chrome I am prompted to add a shortcut to the home screen which I do. When I launch from the shortcut I see a screen like this with a X and site information, as well as a menu of Chrome options:

View after launching PWA from shortcut
[image]

When I click on the cross a blank white screen is displayed like this:

Blank white screen after clicking cross
[image]

The manifest.json includes:

```
    "start_url": "/default.aspx",
    "display": "standalone", 
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "theme_color": "#428BCA",
    "background_color": "#428BCA"
```

If I remove the shortcut, clear the browser cache and reinstall when prompted again the behaviour is unpredictable. Sometimes what I have described above happens but on other occasions a shortcut is created which launches standalone and without the X and site information bar.

I have 3 questions.

1) Why does tapping the X result in a blank white screen being displayed?

2) Why does adding a shortcut (to the same PWA) sometimes result in a standalone launcher and sometimes one which adds the X and site information above the PWA screen?

3) Is it possible to see the url which the shortcut on the home screen is using? When the PWA launches with the X and site information bar it is not possible to grab the url as far as I can tell.

Thanks

Brian

Comment: Follow the correct way on how to Add to Homescreen correctly which was mentioned in [Web App Install Banners and Add to Homescreen for Chrome on Android](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#web_app_install_banners_and_add_to_homescreen_for_chrome_on_android)

Comment: The first image is typically what you see when a PWA for example.com has a user click on a link for otherexample.com. Is your site doing any sort of initial navigation or opening of popups? Maybe for authentication? Without seeing more code and your live site it's unlikely we can diagnose what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to your question number 3:

You can programmatically check the url from JavaScript by accessing the document.location property. For debugging purposes you can eg. write that to the screen or log it to your server or whatnot. Also, if you're able to access your web server's logs, just open your web app from the home screen and watch the logs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
3) Is it possible to see the url which the shortcut on the home screen is using? When the PWA launches with the X and site information bar it is not possible to grab the url as far as I can tell.
```

You can try to use this: "start_url": "/default.aspx?utm_source=homescreen"